# I am getting the following error while upgrading the chaincode using Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I want to upgrade my edited chaincode to the fabric network, but I am getting the following error while upgrading.

This is the command I am using to upgrade the chaincode:

```
composer network upgrade -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n election-system -V 0.0.2
```

Here is the error:

> Upgrading business network definition. This may take a minute...
>
> Error: Error trying to upgrade business network.
>   Error: No valid responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an
>   error: Error: cannot get package for chaincode (land-registry:0.0.2)
>   Command failed

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the BNA first with the new version then you can upgrade.

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile election-system@0.0.2.bna

composer network upgrade --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n election-system -V 0.0.2
```

Comment: after running the upgrade command i am getting the following error  
                                                                                                     
"Upgrading business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to upgrade business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: could not find chaincode with name 'election-system'
Command failed"

Comment: this error suggests that i am writing the name of network wrong, but i am writing election-system only, i dont know whats the problem?

Comment: Maybe inside the BNA, You are not giving the same name. Check for the spelling mistake also.